# How can i avoid browser auto open or close tags when i try to get the html of the text selected

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I´m creating a application for students where user is gonna be able to highlight the text for the document and make comment, now for the highlight of the text i´m just taking the selected text and wrapping the content in a `mark` tag using `window.selection.getRangeAt(0).surroundContents()`, now what i need to do is to get the html of the selection and avoid that browser auto open or close the html tags, for example, i have this text:

Super wonder **ultra mega** promotion.

where the HTML of the text will this `<p>Super wonder <strong>ultra mega</strong> promtion</p>`, if the user select `Super wonder ultra` the HTML i will get back should be `<p>Super wonder <strong>ultra` and in the case the user select `mega promotion` the HTML i should get is `mega </strong> promtion</p>` but because the browser auto open and close tags if i select `Super wonder ultra` the HTML i get back is `<p>Super wonder<strong>ultra</strong></p>`. is there any way to avoid this behavior or to achieve this.

this the function i´m using to get the html of the selection:

```
  public getHtmlSelection(selection: any): string {
    let html: string;
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    for (let i = 0, len = selection.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
      container.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
    }
    html = container.innerHTML;
    return html;
  }
```

and here i highlight the text selected:

```
  public markContent(): void {
    const selection: any = window.getSelection();
    const range: any = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    if (range.startOffset !== range.endOffset) {
      if (this.markerEvent === 'p' || this.markerEvent === 'mark' || this.markerEvent === 'strong') {

        const textSeleted: string = selection.toString();
        const highlight: any = range.commonAncestorContainer;
        if (this.markerEvent !== 'mark') {
          const marker: any = document.createElement('mark');
          marker.setAttribute('class', this.colorMarker);
          range.surroundContents(marker);
          this.hideBubble();
          return;
        }

        const mark: any = range.commonAncestorContainer;

        mark.remove();
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(document.createTextNode(highlight.textContent));
        this.hideBubble();
      }
    }

  }
```

thanks so much for any help or comment. if i´m not to clear please ask i little but more in the comments.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want to do. Do you need a string representation of selected text? you can just use `window.getSelection(0).toString()`

Comment: no, is not a string representation of the selection if the html of the selected text with out the browser auto close and close tag in case the user select the text cros-tag, bean able to get `text</strong> more text</p>` and not `<p><strong>text</strong> more text</p>` that is what browser give to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thanks to @gforce301 i was able to find a solution for the situation, just to put some context to the problem, everything start because i was not able to wrap the text select cros-tags like @gforce301 mention on the solution he post, i was trying to get html in this way:  `bold text</strong> and more text</p>` because my idea was check text and open and close the `mark` tag before of the closing of the `</strong>` tag and open another mark tag at the end and close it at the end of the selection, something like this `<mark>bold text</mark></strong><mark>and more text</mark>` but because the browser close if it find a open tag with out been closed and open tag if it find just the closed one i was getting back this HTML `<p><strong>bold text</strong> and more text</p>`.

after testing the solution of @gforce301 i get to this solution:

```
  public markContent(): void {
    const selection: any = window.getSelection();
    const range: any = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    if (range.startOffset !== range.endOffset) {
        const htmlSelection = this.getHtmlSelection(selection);
        const textSeleted: string = selection.toString();
        const highlight: any = range.commonAncestorContainer;
        if (this.markerEvent !== 'mark') {
          const marker: any = document.createElement('mark');
          marker.setAttribute('class', this.colorMarker);
          marker.innerHTML = htmlSelection;
          range.deleteContents();
          range.insertNode(marker);
          this.hideBubble();
          return;
        }
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.display = 'inline';
        p.style.margin = '0';
        p.innerHTML = highlight.innerHTML;
        highlight.remove();
        range.deleteContents();
        range.insertNode(p);
        this.hideBubble();

    }

  }
```

basically what i´m doing is get HTML of the selection using this function,

```
  public getHtmlSelection(selection: any): string {
    let html: string;
    const container = document.createElement('div');
    for (let i = 0, len = selection.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
      container.appendChild(selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
    }
    html = container.innerHTML;
    return html;
  }
```

i storage the HTML on a constant, create the mark element and insert the HTML of the selection on the new `mark` element i create, remove the selection content and then insert the `mark` node in the selection. in case the user select again the text already highlighted is gonna remove the mark tag from the hold highlighted text.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could do this was to manipulate the `innerHTML` of the `commonAncestorContainer` element. There are 2 cases that have to be handled differently.

1. When the selection starts and stops in the same text node.
2. When the selection starts and stops in a different text node.

I handled those cases by comparing the `anchorNode` and `focusNode` of the selection.

**This code is not a complete solution**

If you insert another paragraph below the first and try highlighting across the 2 paragraphs it will not work. You can not split a `mark` element across 2 block level elements. In order to perform that operation more logic would have to be added to the `markText` function to identify and properly manipulate all the block level elements involved. I did not write that code for you.

```js
document.getElementById('mark').addEventListener('click', markText);

    function markText() {
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        
        if(selection.isCollapsed) return;
        
        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
            sameNode = selection.anchorNode === selection.focusNode,
            startText = '',
            endText = '',
            parentHtml = '';

        if(sameNode) {
            parentHtml = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.innerHTML;
            startText = range.commonAncestorContainer.textContent.substring(range.startOffset, range.endOffset);
            parentHtml = parentHtml.replace(startText, '<mark>' + startText + '</mark>');
            range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.innerHTML = parentHtml;
        }
        else {
            parentHtml = range.commonAncestorContainer.innerHTML;
            startText = range.startContainer.textContent.substring(range.startOffset);
            endText = range.endContainer.textContent.substring(0, range.endOffset);
            parentHtml = parentHtml.replace(startText, '<mark>' + startText);
            parentHtml = parentHtml.replace(endText, endText + '</mark>');
            range.commonAncestorContainer.innerHTML = parentHtml;
        }
    }
```

```html
<p>Super wonder <strong>ultra mega</strong> promotion</p>
<button id="mark">Mark Text</button>
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help, your answer help me to find the solution, i will post it in a couple min.